# Request all pegando apenas ultimo valor (LARAVEL)

Tags: php, laravel

Eu fiz uma function uns dias atrás que salvava várias fotos de uma vez. Funcionou, porém quando fui usar essa function novamente, ela estava apenas pegando o ultimo valor que eu estava mandando. Exemplo: mandei foto1, foto2, foto3. Quando dava um dd na variável que recebia o $request->all(), vinha apenas a foto3. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Comment: Tem como adicionar o HTML + código para que possa exemplificar melhor

Comment: Tente adicionar o código fonte do que esta feito até o momento

Comment: public function salvarImagem(Request $request)
    {
        $imagem = $request->all();

        $this->produtoService->salvarImagem($imagem);

        return response()->json('Imagem salva com sucesso!');
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colocou array '[]' no atributo 'name' e o atributo 'multiple' na tag de arquivos?

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagens[]" multiple />
```

Talvez seja esse o problema.